# Synchronize authentications between two django projects

Tags: django, authentication

I have two separate Django projects with separate databases.

I would like that when a user logs in site A, he is automatically logged into site B.

I thought of doing the following:

- When user log into site A, server A requests server B to create a new session for the user,
- Server A then sends back session information to the user client,
- When the client logs into site B, the session data is sent so that server B considers the user as logged in.

Would that work?
How should I send the session data from the browser to server B (with a cookie?)?

Comment: I would rather use a custom authentication backend which authenticates the user after asking permission to the second server under the hood. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to implement SSO (Single Sign On). If that is the case, take a look at this article:

https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/django-single-sign-on-sso-to-multiple-applications-64637da015f4

Answer (score 1):

You can implement OAuth for Site A. https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html will help you in creating an OAuth server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this options, that allow a kind of database authentication thanks to a pre-defined cookie that will persist through your sessions.

This lines should be placed in both project's settings.py files:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'database_sa'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.domain.com'
```

PD: Please keep in mind that the SECRET_KEY value should be the same in both projects, also.

Comment: This solution works fine only for site and its subdomains.